# when i add opcion forEach method get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem, I have a question entity and an option entity, the relationship is one to many.

but when I want to add the options in the question, it shows me that error, as far as I could find, it is because the question entity is being used while it wants to be updated, but I still don't know how to fix it.

```
@Entity
public class Pregunta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cuestionario_id",nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Cuestionario cuestionario;
    
    private String descripcion;
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pregunta",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    
    private List<Opcion> opciones = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Pregunta() {
        
    }
    
    @JsonCreator
    public Pregunta(@JsonProperty Cuestionario cuestionario,@JsonProperty String descripcion, List<Opcion> opciones) {
        super();
        this.cuestionario = cuestionario;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.opciones = opciones;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Cuestionario getCuestionario() {
        return cuestionario;
    }

    public void setCuestionario(Cuestionario cuestionario) {
        this.cuestionario = cuestionario;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public List<Opcion> getOpciones() {
        return opciones;
    }
    public void setOpciones(List<Opcion> opciones) {
        this.opciones = opciones;
    }

    public void addOpcion(Opcion opcion) {
        this.opciones.add(opcion);
        opcion.setPregunta(this);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Opcion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private boolean correct;
    
    private String content;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pregunta_id",nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Pregunta pregunta;

    public Opcion(boolean correct, String content) {
        super();
        this.correct = correct;
        //this.pregunta = pregunta;
        this.content = content;
    }
    
    public Opcion() {}
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }
    public void setCorrect(boolean correct) {
        this.correct = correct;
    }
    

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public Pregunta getPregunta() {
        return pregunta;
    }

    public void setPregunta(Pregunta pregunta) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
        
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Cuestionario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cuestionario",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Pregunta> preguntas = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_cuestionario_id",nullable = false)
    private TipoCuestionario tipoCuestionario;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public Cuestionario(@JsonProperty int id,@JsonProperty String name,@JsonProperty List<Pregunta> preguntas,@JsonProperty TipoCuestionario tipoCuestionario) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.preguntas = preguntas;
        this.tipoCuestionario = tipoCuestionario;
    }

    public Cuestionario() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Pregunta> getPreguntas() {
        return preguntas;
    }

    public void setPreguntas(List<Pregunta> preguntas) {
        this.preguntas = preguntas;
    }

    public TipoCuestionario getTipoCuestionario() {
        return tipoCuestionario;
    }

    public void setTipoCuestionario(TipoCuestionario tipoCuestionario) {
        this.tipoCuestionario = tipoCuestionario;
    }

    public void addPregunta(Pregunta pregunta) {
        this.preguntas.add(pregunta);
        pregunta.setCuestionario(this);
    }
}
```

```
@Override
    public Cuestionario createCuestionario(CuestionarioDto cuestionario) {
        
        Cuestionario newCuestionario = new Cuestionario();
        
        newCuestionario.setName(cuestionario.getName());
        
        Optional<TipoCuestionario> tipoCuestionarioOpt = tipoCuestionarioRepository.findById(cuestionario.getTipoCuestionario());
        
        if(tipoCuestionarioOpt.isPresent()) {
            newCuestionario.setTipoCuestionario(tipoCuestionarioOpt.get());
        }
        
        cuestionario.getPreguntas().forEach(pregunta->newCuestionario.addPregunta(pregunta));
        cuestionario.getPreguntas().forEach(pregunta->pregunta.getOpciones().forEach(opcion->pregunta.addOpcion(opcion)));  

        cuestionarioRepository.save(newCuestionario);
        
        return newCuestionario;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You posted a lot of code, but can you please also add a stacktrace from the exception and a hint, where it finally points to? Also code how to trigger the exception really would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here

`cuestionario.getPreguntas().forEach(pregunta->pregunta.getOpciones().forEach(opcion->pregunta.addOpcion(opcion)));`

you iterate over `pregunta.getOpciones()` and perform `pregunta.addOpcion(opcion)`

so You modify collection while iterating over it

https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception

BTW it looks like You iterate over `Opciones` in `pregunta` and add `opcion` to `pregunta` you try to duplicate entries ?

Comment: hi,yeah, I want add a column in the opcion entity where I have the id of the question entity,so I did that. If I removed this code , work, but I don't have the reference of the question entity. I'll add the body of the request. Postman